# ie9 background-color issues

Tags: internet-explorer-9

It works in IE7, IE8 BUT not ie9!!  why oh why!!

Simple formula:

I have a solid grey background on the HTML. I have NO background color on the div-outerwrapper but I DO have a background-color on the div-innerwrapper of #fff.

On ie8, the div shows white but not ie9. The developer toolbar also shows that I have a background of #fff. BUT all ie9 shows is the background color I have on my HTML TAG.

Has anyone encountered such a weird bug?

Comment: Could you show some example page source code that exhibits the problem? Also, from what you've written, I suspect that IE9 may be rendering it correctly, along with others like Firefox, and IE7/8 are the ones doing it wrong.